# TYPO3 Log The parsedUri "https:///" appears to be malformed

Tags: logging, typo3, typo3-11.x

Can someone help me out. This error appears every second or so: And i have no clue where it comes from.

---

```
Thu, 19 Oct 2023 08:59:52 +0200 [CRITICAL] request="a6c6e1b6ae6ec" component="TYPO3.CMS.Core.Error.ProductionExceptionHandler": Core: Exception handler (WEB: BE): InvalidArgumentException, code #1436717322, file #######typo3_src-11.5.30/typo3/sysext/core/Classes/Http/Uri.php, line 125: The parsedUri "https:///" appears to be malformed - {"mode":"WEB","application_mode":"BE","exception_class":"InvalidArgumentException","exception_code":1436717322,"file":"#######typo3_src-11.5.30/typo3/sysext/core/Classes/Http/Uri.php","line":125,"message":"The parsedUri \"https:///\" appears to be malformed","request_url":"https:///","exception":null}
```

Thu, 19 Oct 2023 08:59:53 +0200 [CRITICAL] request="3a2bdcc91d8aa" component="TYPO3.CMS.Core.Error.ProductionExceptionHandler": Core: Exception handler (WEB: BE): InvalidArgumentException, code #1436717322, file #######typo3_src-11.5.30/typo3/sysext/core/Classes/Http/Uri.php, line 125: The parsedUri "https:///" appears to be malformed - {"mode":"WEB","application_mode":"BE","exception_class":"InvalidArgumentException","exception_code":1436717322,"file":"#######typo3_src-11.5.30/typo3/sysext/core/Classes/Http/Uri.php","line":125,"message":"The parsedUri "https:///" appears to be malformed","request_url":"https:///","exception":null}

---

I checked the logs and DB for the 'https:///' but no luck. I hoped an Update to v11 would fix it, but it did not.
we have the same Page as DEV on a different Server, there the Problem doesen't appear

Comment: One could use the `DebugExceptionHandler` in a development context, which would show the full exception stack trace. This would make it easier to determine the origin of the `https:///` value.

Comment: ok, i'll try,
a Idea came to my mind.. i'm not the server admin, but could a false or old nginx config cause this problem?

Comment: config.contentObjectExceptionHandler = 0
component="TYPO3.CMS.Core.Error.ProductionExceptionHandler": Core: Exception handler (WEB: BE): InvalidArgumentException, code #1436717322, file /typo3/sysext/core/Classes/Http/Uri.php, line 125: The parsedUri "https:///" appears to be malformed - {"mode":"WEB","application_mode":"BE","exception_class":"InvalidArgumentException","exception_code":1436717322,"file":"typo3_src-11.5.30/typo3/sysext/core/Classes/Http/Uri.php","line":125,"message":"The parsedUri \"https:///\" appears to be malformed","request_url":"https:///","exception":null}

Answer (score 0):

have a look in your site configuration
(`Sites Management`-> `Sites` on tab `general`the field `Entry Point [base]`).

There you should have a full domain.

Maybe you only have a `/` here or in any variant (field `Variants for the Entry Point[baseVariants]`)?

Comment: i can confim that the Site Config is fine..

Answer (score 0):

This is a longer log:

```
Fri, 20 Oct 2023 08:15:38 +0200 [CRITICAL] request="4bec869b88187" component="TYPO3.CMS.Core.Error.DebugExceptionHandler": Core: Exception handler (WEB: BE): InvalidArgumentException, code #1436717322, file /var/www/###/typo3_src-11.5.30/typo3/sysext/core/Classes/Http/Uri.php, line 125: The parsedUri "https:///" appears to be malformed- InvalidArgumentException: The parsedUri "https:///" appears to be malformed, in file /var/www/###/typo3_src-11.5.30/typo3/sysext/core/Classes/Http/Uri.php:125 - {"mode":"WEB","application_mode":"BE","exception_class":"InvalidArgumentException","exception_code":1436717322,"file":"/var/www/###/typo3_src-11.5.30/typo3/sysext/core/Classes/Http/Uri.php","line":125,"message":"The parsedUri \"https:///\" appears to be malformed","request_url":"https:///","exception":"InvalidArgumentException: The parsedUri \"https:///\" appears to be malformed in /var/www/###/typo3_src-11.5.30/typo3/sysext/core/Classes/Http/Uri.php:125\nStack trace:\n#0 /var/www/###/typo3_src-11.5.30/typo3/sysext/core/Classes/Http/Uri.php(111): TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\Http\\Uri->parseUri()\n#1 /var/www/###/typo3_src-11.5.30/typo3/sysext/core/Classes/Http/ServerRequestFactory.php(65): TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\Http\\Uri->__construct()\n#2 /var/www/###/typo3_src-11.5.30/typo3/sysext/core/Classes/Http/AbstractApplication.php(100): TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\Http\\ServerRequestFactory::fromGlobals()\n#3 /var/www/###/typo3_src-11.5.30/index.php(20): TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\Http\\AbstractApplication->run()\n#4 /var/www/###/typo3_src-11.5.30/index.php(21): {closure}()\n#5 {main}"}
```

Answer (score 0):

The source code referenced in the stack trace is at a very early point of the request handling at `\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Http\ServerRequestFactory::fromGlobals` and looks like this:

```php
new Uri(GeneralUtility::getIndpEnv('TYPO3_REQUEST_URL'));
```

At this time of the process, `Site` configuration is not evaluated yet - thus, it also would not cause the mentioned behavior.

`TYPO3_REQUEST_URL` is a computed value, but usually also contains the server environment variable `HTTP_HOST`. Thus, this either could be the result of

- `HTTP_HOST` is empty since it might not be forwarded from the web server (this sounds very unlikely, but still it would be possible), or
- some invalid/incomplete reverse proxy configuration in `$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SYS']['reverseProxyIP']` and/or a filtered `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_HOST` HTTP header

---

The live website does not seem to be affected when requested by a regular browser. Thus, I guess it might be some internal heartbeat monitoring request.

Analyzing the HTTP request revealed some F5 BigIP networking component being used there. Thus, my guess(!) is, that it is somehow related, and that host names are not forwarded to their downstream components.

Comment: There is a Monitoring, i'll check that with the admin, thanx